# removeObserver fails with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, data-binding, key-value-observing

I am observing a core data value with KVO, but when I remove the observer, I get the message:

Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "flightname.value" from  because it is not registered as an observer.

Code below called two times. First time _selectedFlight is null, so removeObserver is not triggered. Second time I want to remove, what first time was assigned. Observer address is not changing.

```
//Remove old binding.
if (_selectedFlight) {
    id oi = [_selectedFlight observationInfo];
    if (![oi isFault]) {
        //NOTE: In somehow I cant remove it.
        [_selectedFlight removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"flightname.value"];
    }
}

_selectedFlight = [_selectedRegistration.flights objectAtIndex:(_selectedRegistration.flights.count - indexPath.row - 1)];

//Bind flightname to the Summary View.
[_selectedFlight addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"flightname.value" options:0 context:NULL];
```

> Here you can see the content of the
>   observationInfo and some details before removeObserver is called.:
>
> (lldb) po oi (id) $1 = 0x06b42d80  ( 
>   Context: 0x0, Property: 0x6b425e0> )
>
> (lldb) po self (MenuViewController *const) $2 = **0x08136f90**
>
> (lldb) po _selectedFlight (Flight *) $3 = 0x06b26770  (entity: Flight; id: 0x6b26ef0
>    ; data:
>   {
>       date = "0x6b1b8f0 ";
>       destination = "0x6b29140 ";
>       flightname = "0x6b29150 ";
>       id = 1;
>       ladc = nil;
>       loadsheet = nil;
>       origin = "0x6b29160 ";
>       registration = "0x6e60700 ";
>       sta = "0xc81fb90 ";
>       std = "0xc8203d0 ";
>       todc = "0x6b293e0 "; })

Comment: This could be an indexing issue - just to debug this, add an additional value to the list of observers in each registration and make sure you're fetching the same one you added the observer to.

Comment: Can you also log the addresses of _selectedFlight and self right before you remove the observer. Just to be sure you are removing the right observer.

Comment: The 0x08136f90 address was not changed meanwhile. The interesting is that if I modify the code, and removeObserver is called right after I added, then no problem, If I am navigating the GUI, and call it later, I get this crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing by this issue in legacy code, and I do the follow :

```
 if (object && object.observationInfo)
    [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"key"];
```

Because my code is legacy, I don't know what is causing this issue, but I discovered that checking the observationInfo property fixed it.

Hope helps.